# Tensorflow tflite c++ api inference for matrix data array

Tags: c++, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am creating a class that will be used to run inference on an embedded device (not raspberry pi) in c++ using tensorflow's tflite c++ api.  Tensorflow doesn't seem to have decent documentation on how to run inference for n number of samples of image data.  My data shape in python is (n, 5, 40, 1) [n samples, 5 height, 40 width, 1 channel].  What I cannot figure out is how to input the data and receive the inference per sample in the output.  I have two classes so I should receive n 2-d array ouputs.  Does anyone know if you can pass in any data type such as an Eigen?  I am testing with an input of shape (1, 5, 2, 1) to simplify my test.

```
#include "classifier.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace tflite;

Classifier::Classifier(std::string modelPath) {
    tflite::StderrReporter error_reporter;
    model = tflite::FlatBufferModel::BuildFromFile(modelPath.c_str(), &error_reporter);

    tflite::ops::builtin::BuiltinOpResolver resolver;
    tflite::InterpreterBuilder(*model, resolver)(&interpreter); // private class variable interpreter
    std::vector<int> sizes = {1, 5, 2, 1};
    interpreter->ResizeInputTensor(0, sizes);
    interpreter->AllocateTensors();


}

std::vector<std::vector<float> Classifier::getDataSamples() {
    std::vector<std::vector<float> test = {{0.02, 0.02}, {0.02, 0.02}, {0.02, 0.02},{0.02, 0.02},{0.02, 0.02},};
    return test;
}

float Classifier::predict() {


    std::vector<float> signatures = getDataSamples();
    for (int i = 0; i < signatures.size(); ++i) {
        interpreter->typed_input_tensor<float>(0)[i];
    }

    // float* input = interpreter->typed_input_tensor<float>(0);
    // *input = 1.0;

    interpreter->Invoke();

    float* output = interpreter->typed_output_tensor<float>(0);

    return *output;
}
```